# Image Update threw generic.UpdateView not working

Tags: python, django

I have a Books model class with the following attributes :

```
class Books(models.Model):

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("books:detail-books", kwargs={"book_id": self.pk})
    .......

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    author = models.CharField(
    verbose_name="Author (if not you)", max_length=200, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    original_poster = models.ForeignKey(
    PersoUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    price = models.DecimalField(
    max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0, validators=[
            MinValueValidator(0)
           ])

   cover = models.ImageField(
        default="cover/default_cover.jpg", upload_to="cover")

   def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.title} de {self.author}"
```

And the user who has posted a book can update it threw a class based view :

```
class UpdateBook(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = Books
    form_class = CreateForm
    template_name = "books/update_book.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.original_poster = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        book = self.get_object()
        if book.original_poster == self.request.user:
            return True
        return False
```

the form :

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:

    model = Books
    exclude = ["original_poster"]
```

When I try to update the price, title or other fields it's working fine but when I try to update the cover image it's not working at all and no error is displayed. It's working when directly updating from the django administration, does anyone have a clue ? I'm quite confused since there is no ptoblem with other fields, thanks in advance

Comment: I just noticed that when trying to post a book threw a similat generic.CreateView class even when choosing a different cover it's the default one which is saved in the db

Answer (score 0):

just forgot to add enctype="multipart/form-data" in my template